# Google Sheet - counting number of Unique values with blank cell value beside it

Tags: google-sheets

I have sheet with 2 columns where data in first column includes dates and 2nd column includes numbers. I want to "scan" down the row of the first column and count the number of unique values, and then count if those unique values have value on the 2nd column. Hope you can help!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To count the number of unique dates that have data in 'Daily Volume', try

```
=countunique(filter(A2:A, len(B2:B)))
```

Change range to suit.